# Unrar archive with folders in Debian?

Tags: linux, directory, rar

I have the task: I have the Windows-made rar-archive (folders, files in it and so on), that via FTP was copied to Linux server.
I want to unrar this archive to keep the file structure as it was in Windows - with folder.

```
rar у my_archivive
```

works, but I have just the list of files without folders.

How to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`man unrar` says

```
x      Extract files with full path.
```